# Javascript input styling - function stops at first IF

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I would like to implement live input data validation in Javascript, unfortunately it always stops on first IF (red field border - too short length). Do you know what could cause that?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" minlength="3" maxlength=12 pattern="[a-zA-z]" onkeydown="validateName()" required>
```

JS

```
  let nameValue = document.getElementById("fullname")


function validateName(){
  if(nameValue.innerText.length<3){
  nameValue.setAttribute("style","border-color:red")
}
  else if(nameValue.innerText.length>=3 && nameValue.innerText.length<=12){
    nameValue.setAttribute("style", "border-color:green")
  }
  else{
    nameValue.setAttribute("style", "border-color:red")
  }
}
```

Comment: Some awkwardness in code here overall, in any case, how come you're checking `innerText` instead of `value`? With any input field, `value` should be the primary thing you deal with.

Comment: Side note: an element without a closing tag should end with a slash: `<input />`, not `<input>`.

Comment: `else if(nameValue.innerText.length>=3` - superfluous to check for that at this point - you are in the else branch of `if(nameValue.innerText.length<3)`, and a length is always an integer - so _of course_ it is >= 3 here in any case, even without your additional check.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Thank you for help with input. Would you be so kind to show, how you will write it to work more fluent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to track the event using the target variable returned from the event.

```js
function validateName(e) {
  if (e.target.value.length < 3) {
    e.target.style.borderColor = "red"
  } else if (e.target.value.length >= 3 && e.target.value.length <= 12) {
    e.target.style.borderColor = "green"
  } else {
    e.target.style.borderColor = "red"
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" minlength="3" maxlength=12 pattern="[a-zA-z]" oninput="validateName(event)" required />
```

Comment: Or if kept outside the function, don't declare it with `let`.

Comment: May thanks mr Vishnudev, it works perfectly. I have only question about "oninput="validateName(event)" and "function validateName(e)" -> how does it work that event and e, hard to understand where this e come from.

Comment: `e` is just short-form for "event" and refers to the event the has occurred (key input). If you `console.log(e)` you will see a huge variety of properties, including `e.target` which refers to the element that originated the event (in this case, an input field). You can use whatever name you want in place of `e` but the typical thing to do is use `e` or `event`, that way it's easy to understand. Nothing stopping you from using some arbitrary word like "theEventThatOccurred", but it's not elegant.